# How can I scrape historical data when date range is in a filter?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some historical data on the following url: https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=LU0526609390:EUR
I would like to scrape all the available historical data, however, the website only allows me to scrape the daily prices of the last 30 days. In order to go back further, I have to make use of the filters and can only filter one year at a time.

I can easily scrape the information available on the first table using the following code for a couple of funds:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv

urls = ['https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=LU0526609390:EUR', 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', 
'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=LU1076093779:EUR', 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=LU1116896363:EUR']

# Change date format as there appears to be two versions of the date on the FT website for different sized browsers

def format_date(date):
    date = date.split(',')[-2][1:] + date.split(',')[-1]

    return pd.Series({'Date': date})

# Create list to allow all scraping data to be saved in one .csv file

dfs = []

# Create scraping loop for all defined urls

for url in urls:
    ISIN = url.split('=')[-1].replace(':', '_')
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = df_list[-1]
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(format_date)
    print (df)
    dfs.append(df)
```

However, I'm unable to make use of the filters on the webpage to obtain more historical data? I've tried many things but always get a different error message. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from an api that allows to set date ranges, eg `https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/get-historical-prices?startDate=2020/10/01&endDate=2021/10/01&symbol=535700333`. This makes it possible to skip the filters issue:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

#create list of annual dates for the past 100 years starting from today
datelist = pd.date_range(end=datetime.now(),periods=100,freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))[::-1].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
#create empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'])

#not sure when the historical data starts, so let's wrap it in a while loop
while True:
    for end, start in zip(datelist, datelist[1:]):
        try:
            r = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/get-historical-prices?startDate={start}&endDate={end}&symbol=535700333').json()
            df_temp = pd.read_html('<table>'+r['html']+'</table>')[0]
            df_temp.columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']
            df = df.append(df_temp)
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            break
    break
```

Output:

|  | Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Friday, October 15, 2021Fri, Oct 15, 2021 | 78.8 | 78.8 | 78.8 | 78.8 | ---- |
| 1 | Thursday, October 14, 2021Thu, Oct 14, 2021 | 78.89 | 78.89 | 78.89 | 78.89 | ---- |
| 2 | Wednesday, October 13, 2021Wed, Oct 13, 2021 | 78.7 | 78.7 | 78.7 | 78.7 | ---- |
| 3 | Tuesday, October 12, 2021Tue, Oct 12, 2021 | 78.58 | 78.58 | 78.58 | 78.58 | ---- |
| 4 | Monday, October 11, 2021Mon, Oct 11, 2021 | 78.58 | 78.58 | 78.58 | 78.58 | ---- |

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I didn't spot that the data was loaded from an API...Makes my life a lot easier!